# Reevaluate the historical lock on "What are the things Java got right?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-question

The question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120560/what-are-the-things-java-got-right is a poll. It has 41 answers. Beyond the top answer (which is repeated countless times in blogs out there), the answers quickly devolve into poor ones that are debatable or repeating previous answers (garbage collection is mentioned in the question, and three of the top four answers by votes, similarly platform independence, library).

> - A googlable name. Try googling for "C"...
> - A standard library that is somewhat consistent.
> - A fast and open standardization process.

> Checking bounds of all array accesses and validity of all casts.

> Nobody seems to have mentioned **Enumerations**. They've done quite a nice job on those.

> Competition

Either this should be a wiki lock (and I really don't like it - again, its in countless blog posts out there), or deleted.  The question only has ~1470 views. Its really not worth keeping around beyond as serving as an example of why we do big lists questions poorly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wholeheartedly agree.  I unlocked and deleted this question.  The views just don't justify keeping it around.

If you disagree and would like Wiki Answer Lock this instead then please volunteer.  I think it is too much work for too little benefit honestly.

As a side note, I am astonished at 40+ answers and < 2,000 views.  That is a high answer to view ratio, maybe a contender?  Would make for an interesting SEDE query.

Comment: SEDE suggests that there was only two anonymous vote on any of it ( http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/220020/qa-anon-feedback?QuestionId=120560 ).  It just wasn't viewed and after the first splurge of activity sat well behind the other good blog posts out there that answer the question better. It wasn't something that we'd dup to. It just kind of sat and languished when compared to other sites that do that type of question better.

Comment: Aside, given the age of the original question compared to its postid, it is possible it might have been a Stack Overflow migration of old posts or a merge somewhere in the history (though I didn't see it in the revisions) that might have lost some of its early (Stack Overflow?) popularity. That said, since it has been here it has still failed to gain any significant number of views between '11 (anna's edit), '13 (the great locking and unlocking and locking), and '15 (now).